# Django spaceless template tag breaks Bootstrap rendered content

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, twitter-bootstrap-3

Django templating language comes with a nice `{% spaceless %}...{% endspaceless %}` tag which allow to remove every whitespace, tab, newline... between html tags.

The problem is that Bootstrap seems to be "**space sensitive**": when using `spaceless`, form elements such as inputs and buttons are "sticked" each other.

Here is a an illustration: http://jsfiddle.net/KNkqF/ is not rendered as http://jsfiddle.net/E5rU5/ !

Have you ever faced this problem and did you manage to get rid of it without avoiding Django spaceless?

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap is setting those input elements to `display: inline-block;` and not floating or setting them to display as `display: block;`. You may want to hard code a `&nbsp;` in between the inputs to force the space.

---

```
<span style="display:block; float:left;">hello</span> <span style="display:block; float:left;">world</span>
```

The two spans above will line up right next to each other even though there is a space between them results in "helloworld".

---

```
<span>hello</span> <span>world</span>
```

The two spans above will have a space between them result in "hello world"

---

```
<span>hello</span><span>world</span>
```

Will result in.. "helloworld".

---

I've never used spaceless in a form before but because it is cleaning up all of the spaces this would do it.

Are you using django-bootstrap-form or handwriting your forms?

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I use both django-crispy-forms and handwritten forms. It seems quite weird to me to have to insert &nbsp; in my code (despite of this is the solution I currently use :s). Won't &nbsp;s break some responsive features?

Comment: Yes it could break some future things. I guess, my next question is how come you are using spaceless on a form? Are you using it just on the form or wrapping all of the page's content in it? You could use the spaceless tag twice on the page so that it excludes the form or you could modify the bootstrap css so that the `.form-inline .form-group`class has a margin. I think the best way would be to not use spaceless here..

Comment: Hum, yes, I wrap all my base template content in a spaceless tag, which ensures my html is always as tiny as possible!